# Why do these two nodes not compare equal?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I've got some HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>a pargraph</p>
</body>
</html>
```

For which I grab the `body` and `p` node, and then I tried

```
Console.WriteLine(p.ParentNode == body);
```

And it's telling me False. Why is that? I need this functionality in my program...

Comment: What does `p.ParentNode.Equals(body)` tell you?

Comment: Yep, looking at the source for `HtmlNode`, I don't see any helpful overrides.

Comment: I think I can get around this by comparing their XPaths... but... still dumb.

Answer (score 3):

That's because the equality operator is not overridden! Try using

```
p.ParentNode.XPath == body.XPath
```

instead!

Comment: I am outraged. The questioner still didn't mark your answer as correct!%)

Comment: @MAKKAM: I can't for another 2 days :(